# git: find most recent non-rename commit to a file

Tags: git, git-log, git-rev-list, git-mv

`git rev-list` outputs all version of a file path (stops at renames), `git --follow --pretty=%h` outputs all versions across moves/renames, but how can I find (non-manually) the latest commit that modified the content of a file (preferably excluding `chmod`'s too)?

In my case I have a file that was renamed several times, but I want to rebase just before the latest commit that changed it.

Comment: `git log -n1 --follow -- yourfile`.  After `--` you can specify some files (only one with `--follow`). In this case `git log` shows you only commits that modified these files.

Comment: Yes, I've noted that in the post; `git --follow` also shows commits that **moved** a file, while I want only commits that changed the content of a file